# gitlab-runner: Service is not running error when install it with docker

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running gitlab-runner with docker. I used to create a container with following command:

```
docker run -d --name runner --restart always -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

then I exec the container with this command:

```
docker exec -it runner bash
```

and when I want to see the status of gitlab-runner it says

"gitlab-runner: Service is not running"

while when I restart gitlab-runner service with

```
/etc/init.d/gitlab-runner restart
```

it returns true and stop and start the service.
what is the problem exaclty?

Comment: Have you tried starting daemon `gitlab-runner` as `docker run` entrypoint or command?

Comment: @AlejandroGalera Honestly I dont grasp your meaning :(

Comment: It looks it's been launched in a different way than `/etc/init.d/gitlab-runner start`, so, I'd check command or entrypoint executed by default when you do `docker run`. You can check it doing `docker inspect runner` or entering with `docker exec -it runner bash` and check with `ps` which process has been launched with pid=1. It's probable that it's been launched as `gitlab-runner run --user=gitlab-runner --working-directory=/home/gitlab-runner` and there's a bug in init.d script to show status correctly.